# Keras Error on Convolutional Layer and Input Data

Tags: python, machine-learning, tensorflow, deep-learning, keras

I filtered the training and testing data from CIFAR-100, I take for fruit and vegetables superclass only. Now, I've 2,500 training and 500 testing data. But, I got an error said that wrong dimension input for Convolutional layer.

[image: Error]

My array data form:
[image: Array form]

I hope someone can help me for this case, thank you.

Comment: Please post code and the error in text.

Comment: Here is the full code: http://pastebin.com/dGBSL7dJ   
and the error: http://pastebin.com/dhy4wRhG

Answer (score 1):

Your input data should have shape (2500, 3, 32, 32), seems you lost two of the dimensions on your preprocessing steps, either fix those or reshape your data as:

```
inputData = inputData.reshape((2500, 3, 32, 32)).
```

In general the input for a convolutional layer is (numSamples, numChannels, width, height). Note that when using the tensorflow backend the number of channels dimension goes at the end.

Comment: Thanks, @Matias. You mean I should doing `X_train.reshape((3, 32, 32))`, `y_train.reshape((3, 32, 32))`, `X_test.reshape((3, 32, 32))`, and `y_test.reshape((3, 32, 32))` first before running `model.fit(...)`?

Comment: no, just reshape X, not y, and I gave you the exact command to do it.

Comment: Yes, note that the shapes change if you use tensorflow.

Comment: I added: `X_train = X_train.reshape((2500, 32, 32, 3))` and `X_test = X_test.reshape((500, 32, 32, 3))` But, I got an error like this: pastebin.com/EQj4t2ca.

But, with `X_train = X_train.reshape((2500, 3, 32, 32))` and `X_test = X_test.reshape((500, 3, 32, 32))`, it works. I don't know why, I used TensorFlow backend.

Comment: This depends on your dim_ordering, defined in ~/.keras/keras.json. By the way I would emplore you to look at how you read your data. I would strongly advise you not to reshape your data unnecessarily or at least look at the images you feed into the network to make sure they are correct. I use a notebook for those tasks.

Comment: @thomas-pinetz I've run the training process and testing a class prediction for some external images and luckily it predicted correctly. Is it mean my layer already correct?

Comment: Maybe, I was in a similar situation. The model kinda worked, but not as well as it should have and when i looked at the image, I noticed that it was off. I just advise you to carefully look at the actual training data used to train your model.